# Issues with un-hiding table after controller action returns model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a hidden table, that is being filled by a controller action returning a model. I have been trying to use the same method I have previously to un-hide the table (via JS toggle) however, once the button is clicked, table becomes visible for a brief second, but as soon as the controller action returns the model, the table is hidden again. Below is my code:

HTML:

form with btn

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm"}))
 {
    <div class="row">
        @*<input type="text" name="CasinoID" placeholder="Enter Casino ID" id="cIdSearch" />*@
        <div>
            Casino: @Html.DropDownList("CasinoID", Model.TerminalReceiptPostData.CasinoIdDDL, "Select Casino", new { id = "cIdSearch", @class = "custom-class-for-dropdown card" })
        </div>
        &nbsp;
        <div>
            Date: <input id="datepicker" class="datepicker-base card" name="Date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/>
        </div>
        &nbsp;
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="search" onclick="toggleTable()"> Search Transactions</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

hidden table:

```
<hr />
<div class="row hidden" id="ReceiptsMainDiv">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow-y:scroll">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="terminalReceipts">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Terminal ID</th>
                    <th>Local Transaction Time</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Receipt</th>
                    <td class="hidden"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (var item in Model.TransactionsTests)
                {
                    <tr id="@String.Concat("rowIndex", Model.TransactionsTests.IndexOf(item))">
                        <td>@item.TerminalID</td>
                        <td>@item.TransactionTime</td>
                        <td>@item.Amount</td>
                        @*<td>@Html.ActionLink("View Receipt", "ViewReceipt", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" }) <br /></td>*@
                        <td class="transactionID hidden">@item.Id</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (item.ReceiptData == null)
                            {
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary viewReceipt" disabled>View Receipt</button>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary viewReceipt" data-rowindex="@String.Concat("rowIndex", Model.TransactionsTests.IndexOf(item))">View Receipt</button>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string CasinoID, DateTime Date)
    {

        //var id = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["CasinoID"].ToString());

        var Cid = Request.Form["CasinoID"];
        Cid = GetNumbers(Cid);

        var id = Int32.Parse(Cid);

        var model = TRBL.GetTransactionTestsData(id, Date);
        model.TerminalReceiptPostData = TRBL.GetCasinosDDL();
        return View(model);
    }
```

JS:

```
  function toggleTable() {

    $("#ReceiptsMainDiv").toggle();

}
```

What's a better way to get around this?? Thank you!

Comment: Your button has two functions: first it toggles table visibility, then it triggers the default action, which is submitting the form. What you see is the way it should work. But what is the behaviour you actuslly want instead?

Comment: @ZorgoZ it actually does the exact same if I place it in either one.

Comment: @ZorgoZ I just want the table to be shown after the model is returned and to remain visible.

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

It looks like what is happening is, you are hiding the div container for the table by default, and you are attempting to show the table when the "Search Transactions" button is clicked.

The problem is clicking that button, since it is your form's "submit" button, will refresh the page. This would mean your toggle code won't be called after the page refreshes. (*It will be called before the page refreshes, which is why you briefly see the result*).

Assuming that you are looking to hide the table **unless** there is something in it (e.g., hide table **only** when there is no data loaded), then you have a couple of options, one of which I will suggest below.

### Suggested Solution

- Remove your "onClick" from the submit/"Search Transactions" button
- Remove your function that onClick calls
- Place javascript that activates when the page is loaded

  - Toggle the div ( 
    `$("#ReceiptsMainDiv").toggle();` ) to "unhide" it **only** if data exists within the table, within the document load javascript function.

Since I don't have the model class I wouldn't be able to tell you how you would determine whether or not there is data, but:

- If the model is a single set of values (say, a single "transaction"), then you probably have an `Id` field

  - Look for that `Id` field to be something other than its default value.  If it is an `int`, checking for `Id > 0` should be sufficient.
- If the model is a **collection** of "transactions", look for the `Count > 0` on the collection itself.

Hope this helps!